# Errors in installing MariaDB in WSL2

Tags: mariadb, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am trying to install MariaDB in WSL2, but it's showing me the following errors -

```
sachinpandeyatd@DESKTOP-Q3O2EQE:/mnt/c/Users/Hp/documents/server$ sudo apt-get install mariadb-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mariadb-server : Depends: mariadb-server-10.3 (>= 1:10.3.29-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I'd be very grateful if anyone can resolve my error!!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I its not a programming question, and even though its WSL, it appears to be an ubuntu question best asked on https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: And why should I ask only programming questions?? Your 2nd point is right, though.

Comment: [on-topic stack overflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: "software tools commonly used by programmers; and is"

Comment: Anyway, I've found a solution, thank you for showing intrest

Comment: What was the solution? I have the same problem and can't find an answer that works!

Comment: @bolvo I am sorry, I don't remember the solution now, also now I am not using WSL, so really sorry, I can't help you.